# How to add chunks with a webpack plugin

Tags: webpack

I'm working on improving the extjs-reactor webpack plugin that makes it easy for  React developers to use Ext JS components.

The plugin uses a Sencha build tool called Sencha Cmd to tree-shake Ext JS and produce a minimal build of the framework that contains only those components used by your app.

Currently the plugin uses the parser API to identify which components are used, and then sends that list of components to Sencha Cmd in the "emit" phase of the build.

I'd love to be able to take the resulting js and css bundles from Sencha Cmd and feed that back into webpack as additional chunks so that other plugins like the HtmlWebpackPlugin could do useful things with them (link add them to the index.html file).

I'm not quite sure how to do that, or if this is even the right approach.  Can anyone offer any guidance or examples of other plugins that do something similar?

I should also mention that I'm working with webpack 1.